# Is there a gem that can be used to list the contents of non-zip archives?

Tags: ruby, jruby, archive

I'm working on a project that needs to get a file list from a variety of different archives files (tar.gz, rar, tar.bz2, and zip) **without** expanding the archive. Rubyzip works well for zip files, but I can't find any equivalent for the other formats. Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that this needs to be cross-platform, so I can't fall back on outside tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of something which handles all formats, but you could do this with a shell call and a little bit of parsing of the result.